# Loop a list of text files in same directory and findstr "keyword" in the txt file (batch script)

Tags: loops, batch-file, scripting

I would like to create a script where loop through all the `.txt` files in the same directory and search for `keyword`.

If `keyword` is found, echo the `filename.txt` and `keyword found` to a `temp.txt`
Else echo the `filename.txt` and `keyword not found` to a `temp.txt`

Current code:

```
for /r D:\Users\hi\Documents\bat_for_random %%X in (*.txt) 
findstr "HELLO KEYWORD " %%X &&
(
echo "keyword found" %%X  >temp.txt
)
|| (
echo "keyword not found" %%X  >temp.txt
)
pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) syntax is wrong, the `do` keyword is missing. In addition, you placed `&&`/`||` and the parentheses wrongly, you need to put them in one line. Finally, your redirection operator `>` overwrites the text file `temp.txt` every time the loop iterates; using `>>` instead would append to the text file; or, even better, you can redirect all the lines once only. So here is the improved code:

```cmd
> "temp.txt" (
    for /R "D:\Users\hi\Documents\bat_for_random" %%X in ("*.txt") do (
        > nul findstr /C:"HELLO KEYWORD " "%%~X" && (
            echo keyword found "%%~nxX"
        ) || (
            echo keyword not found "%%~nxX"
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have two lists, one containing matches and one not. In the real world you need one or the other.

To get a list of the files with string matches is a single command line, *(no need for `For` loops etc.)*:

```dos
FindStr/SMC:"HELLO KEYWORD " "D:\Users\hi\Documents\bat_for_random\*.txt">"temp.txt"
```

Comment: May I know how about I would like to compare two matches like "Hello KEYWORD" and "BYE KEYWORD" in the same file. Both keyword may not need to be in the same line of text but both are inside the same .txt file